# How to add Google bigquery JDBC driver with dependencies from folder

Tags: scala, jdbc, google-bigquery

I have an application to connect various data source developed by Scala. I am using JDBC drivers to connect data sources / databases. All drivers were registered to applicaton via DriverShim. I don't use sbt or maven to add JDBC jar files. Here my DriverShim class..

```
class DriverShim(val driver: Driver) extends Driver {

    override def acceptsURL(url: String): Boolean = this.driver.acceptsURL(url)

    override def connect(url: String, info: Properties): Connection = {
        val c = this.driver.connect(url, info)
        c
    }...
}
```

Here my method to load jdbc driver..

```
def loadJar(path: Path, className: String): Unit = {
    val u = new URL(s"jar:file:${path.toString}!/") 
    val ucl = new URLClassLoader(Array(u))
    val driver = Class.forName(className, true, ucl).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Driver]
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new DriverShim(driver))
}
```

Here How I call loadJar method. Every JDBC driver has own folder and keep in it.

```
loadJar(Path.of("C:\\MyPath\\drivers", "bigquery", "GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar"), "com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.Driver")
```

Now I am trying to add Google Bigquery JDBC driver but I could not add this. I am following this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers .  After unzipped the jdbc file, I keep GoogleBigQueryJDBC42.jar and all together in the same folder along with the other dependencies in it.

Here what document says to referencing the libraries

> **Referencing the JDBC Connector Libraries**
> Before you use the Simba Google BigQuery JDBC Connector, the JDBC application
> or Java code that you are using to connect to your data must be able to access the
> connector JAR files. In the application or code, specify all the JAR files that you
> extracted from the ZIP archive.

> **Using the Connector in a JDBC Application**
> Most JDBC applications provide a set of configuration options for adding a list of
> connector library files. Use the provided options to include all the JAR files from the
> ZIP archive as part of the connector configuration in the application. For more
> information, see the documentation for your JDBC application.

> **Using the Connector in Java Code**
> You must include all the connector library files in the class path. This is the path that
> the Java Runtime Environment searches for classes and other resource files. For
> more information, see "Setting the Class Path" in the appropriate Java SE
> Documentation.

When I try to create connection I get this error..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory
> .................................
> at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)....

When I add all dependencies using with sbt, I can create connection but I don't want to add all bigquery dependencies via sbt. Because I need to add various JDBC driver and all have different libraries with different version. I need to add any JDBC driver with classpath. [Like this..](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1615888-jdbc-connection-to-google-bigquery-database)

Is anyone have an idea to adding JDBC driver with classpath in scala. Or any other solution?

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094449/15747106) answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I use "*" instead of jar file name like this  `Path.of("C:\\MyPath\\drivers", "bigquery", "*")` I get **java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 45: C:\MyPath\drivers\bigquery\***

Comment: `val u = new URL(s"jar:file:C:\\MyPath\\drivers\\bigquery\\*!/")



val ucl = new URLClassLoader(Array(u), this.getClass.getClassLoader)`

When I try to call URL class loader I get **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.Driver** error while creating driver instance.